# Quit while-loop if statement is true

Tags: perl, loops

I have a subfunction and inside of it I am reading a file in Perl with the usual `while`-loop line-by-line because that's the only (and best?) option I know in Perl so far. Now I am searching line-based for a keyword with a loop like

```
my $var;
open(FILE, "stuff.dat")
while (my $line = <FILE>){
   if ($line =~ /regex/) {
      $var = $1;
      return $var;
   } else {
      return "var is not defined!";
   }
}
close(FILE);
```

but even when it gets the keyword and `$var` is specified, it gets overwritten on the next line. So I want to quit the `while`-loop if the keyword is found and `$var` is defined.

I tried `next if` or `next unless` or the `last`-exit but this isn't working properly and [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) states that we can't use `last` for subs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open(my $FILE, "<", "stuff.dat") or die $!;
while (my $line = <$FILE>){
   if ($line =~ /regex/) {
      return $1 if defined $1;
   }
}
close($FILE);
return "var is not defined!";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves the `FILE` filehandle open once the sub has finished. That could be solve by using lexical filehandles.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(FILE, "stuff.dat")
my $var;
while (my $line = <FILE>){
   if ($line =~ /regex/) {
      $var = $1;
      last;
}
}
close(FILE);
return $var;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't working if the regex isn't matched. And this was the behaviour I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the regexp evaluation to the while loop condition, without using return or last.

```
sub check_file {
    open(FILE, "stuff.dat") or die;

    my $result;
    my $line;

    while (($line = <FILE>) && ($result = ($line !~ m/regex/))) {};

    close(FILE);
    ## $result equals 1 only if we have exit the loop and 
    ## didn't have a match till the last line of the file
    return ($result != 1);
}
```